# How to get video duration and video Artist name in PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, image-uploading

I want to know how to get the duration and Video Artist Name on upload video file in PHP. The file can be in any video format.

Comment: These variables (Duration, Video Artist Name) would need to be added along with the video file when they are first uploaded there is no reasonable way to retrieve that information given a video file only in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add these variables when the video is uploaded by the user or yourself there is no reasonable way (that doesn't involve lots of work) to get that information given only a video file in php.

Something like

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
     <input type="text" name="video_name" placeholder="Video Name">
     <input type="text" name="video_duration" placeholder="Video Duration">
     <input type="file" name="video_file">
</body>
```

Then in your php script you retrieve the post variables and add it to a database table or whatever you want to do with it, your question is short on details.

You could also use [php-mp4info](https://code.google.com/archive/p/php-mp4info/) library to read the video file meta data but that requires every video has meta data attached.